# Is there any way to exactly implement a "desktop mode" function into my mobile app when loading website content?

Tags: java, android, http, webview, webkit

Is there any way to exactly implement a "desktop mode" function into my mobile app when loading website content? I'm making a android app, and I want to have a page just with static website content just like in a web browser, I really like how mobile opera implemented this feature, So I just want to know if there is a way to do that. And if there is, then How?

(I'm making this project in Java and viewing the website using WebView from the library "WebKit")

I've also tried changing the User Agent, which didn't work on a static website.

Answer (score 1):

This method helps you to set DesktopMode on webview

```
public void setDesktopMode(WebView webView,boolean enabled) {
    String newUserAgent = webView.getSettings().getUserAgentString();
    if (enabled) {
        newUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5)\nAppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/85\nVersion/11.1.1 Safari/605.1.15";
    }

    webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(newUserAgent);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(enabled);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(enabled);
    webView.reload();
}
```

Call it like that

Mobile mode : `setDesktopMode(webView, false);`

Desktop mode : `setDesktopMode(webView, true);`

**For Kotlin:**

```
fun setDesktopMode(webView: WebView, enabled: Boolean) {
    var newUserAgent: String? = webView.settings.userAgentString
    if (enabled) {
        newUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_5)\nAppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/85\nVersion/11.1.1 Safari/605.1.15"
    }
    webView.settings.apply {
        userAgentString = newUserAgent
        useWideViewPort = enabled
        loadWithOverviewMode = enabled
    }
    webView.reload()
}
```

Comment: I also found this yesterday on stack overflow, but that didn't exactly fork for me either... I'm attaching my code here: https://pastebin.com/ZCNKYegQ

Comment: I updated my answer. Please note that for desktop mode, most important thing is USER-AGENT. As server checks it and gives the responding UI according to the UA. You were using it wrong.

Comment: And no need to load ur page manually, if you give proper UA. The page will look Desktop automatically.